# RMSE significance

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, linear, rms

I am running linear regression, I have over 80,000 observations and 5 predictor variables.

I am trying to pick the best model with RMSE and R-squared and I understand how all that works but...

What is a significant difference between RMSE's ? For example, one model has RMSE = **2664.02** and the other has RMSE = **2665.13**

What do I do? They are literally the same. Do I run the model with less variables? R-square values are almost identical also. What would be a significant RMSE difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your RMSEs are calculated on holdout samples, correct?

You will need to get a handle on the variability of the RMSE. I would recommend a mixture between a bootstrap and cross validation: randomly pick 80% of your data, fit both models to these samples, use the fitted models to predict the remaining 20%, note both RMSE. Repeat many (e.g., 1,000) times. Assess the overlap between the two RMSE distributions, or conduct a paired t-test.

And of course, statistical difference is not the same as practical difference, especially in a case such as this one.